# React.useMemo vs React.useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see other ask about `useState + useEffect`.
but I'm wonder what is the different for unchanged (const) variable in the two implementation :

```js
function optionA(){
  const [Mesh]  = useState(()=> new Mesh)
  
 return "...someRender"
}

function optionB(){
 const Mesh = useMemo(()=> new Mesh)

 return "...someRender"
}
```

Edited:

I know `useRef(someValue)` is more fit for that but I find it "undeclaratively" to write `Mesh.current` anywhere

Comment: Both of those examples will cause an error because you're trying to use `Mesh` before it has a value (because the inner `const` shadows any `Mesh` constructor that may be defined outside the components). Presumably you meant the `Mesh` on the left-hand side to be `mesh` or similar. Similarly, component functions must start with an upper case character if use with JSX, so `OptionA` and `OptionB`.

Comment: like the answer below mentioned why would you use useState as a constant tho? you can simply use useRef for this

Answer (score 6):

The key bit is where you said "unchanged." There's no point in having a value in state that never changes. The purpose of state is to hold information that, when *changed*, will cause a rendering update. If you never change it, there's no reason to put it in state.

**But**, don't use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) for this. From the documentation:

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.** In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without `useMemo` — and then add it to optimize performance.

*(their emphasis)*

If you have information you want to hold statically for the entire lifetime of your component, use `useRef`, not `useMemo`:

```
function Example() {
    const refMesh = useRef(null);
    if (!refMesh.current) {
        // One-time initialization
        refMesh.current = new Mesh();
    }
    const mesh = refMesh.current;
    // ...use `mesh` from here on out...
}
```

Unlike `useMemo`, you can be certain that only a single `Mesh` instance is created during the lifecycle of the component. (This also has the other slight advantage that you aren't constantly creating a function to pass `useMemo` on each render.)

I sometimes use a single ref storing an object to hold multiple pieces of instance information that isn't appropriate for state (including stable callback functions for child components). It's quite handy.

---

Re your edit:

> I know `useRef(someValue)` is more fit for that but I find it "undeclaratively" to write `Mesh.current` anywhere

You don't. See the `const mesh = refMesh.current;` above, you'd use `mesh`, not `refMesh.current`, throughout the remainder of the component.

If you find the `if` awkward, you can wrap this in a hook that provides the semantic guarantee that `useMemo` doesn't provide, at the cost of creating a function on every render (as with `useMemo`, `useCallback`, etc.):

```
const useData = (instanceInitializer) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    if (!ref.current) {
        ref.current = instanceInitializer();
    }
    return ref.current;
};
```

Then it would be:

```
function Example() {
    const mesh = useData(() => new Mesh());
    // ...use `mesh` from here on out...
}
```

That has the (very) slight extra cost of the function creation, but better ergonomics.

Comment: would've been better if you initialised refMesh inside useEffect don't you think so ?

Comment: @سعيد - No, not at all. Why would you think that? Then I wouldn't have that information on the first render, which would be important for (for instance) passing it to child components.

Comment: @perymimon - I've added to the answer to address the edit.

Comment: I agree with you but still not using useEffect makes your render function impure tho

Comment: @سعيد - No more so than any render function using `useState`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`, or (for that matter) `useEffect` -- after all, `useEffect` sets up a side-effect. Side-effects = impure. Nearly all function components are impure. That's why they're "function components," not "functional components." :-)

Comment: ok the last edit, `useData`, looks more convenient. but what is the disadvantage of just using `useState` .  `useState` are already exists and it readable